How to setup sentry for django celery-beat?
I've setup sentry in my demo python project in settings.py.
sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn=os.getenv('SENTRY_KEY'),
    # Set traces_sample_rate to 1.0 to capture 100%
    # of transactions for performance monitoring.
    traces_sample_rate=1.0,
    # Set profiles_sample_rate to 1.0 to profile 100%
    # of sampled transactions.
    # We recommend adjusting this value in production.
    # profiles_sample_rate=1.0,
)

Now I want to enable it for the celery-beat. What is the way to integrate it or update the existing config in settings.py?
The Sentry doc says:

Initialize Sentry in the celeryd_init or beat_init signal

Does it require to create a celery task.py?How to automatically start this task when running python manage.py runserver or celery?

In order for your Beat tasks to run, you need to make sure you have started all of the following:

The Django server, with python manage.py runserver.
The Celery worker, with celery -A [app_name] worker.
The Celery Beat service, with celery -A [app_name] beat.

In order for Sentry to work properly, you need to initialize the SDK in Django, as well as in the Celery worker and the Celery beat service. You can do this by defining an init_sentry function, which is listening to the signals you mentioned in your original post, like in the following example. Make sure to also set monitor_beat_tasks=True in the CeleryIntegration's constructor.
@signals.beat_init.connect
@signals.celeryd_init.connect
def init_sentry(**kwargs):
    sentry_sdk.init(
        ...,
        integrations=[CeleryIntegration(monitor_beat_tasks=True),
    )

Lastly, make sure you call the init_sentry function within your settings.py so that the Python SDK is initialized in your Django server.

You can initialize the Sentry connection to both Django and Celery using below method if you want the logs to be pushed to same DSN
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration
from sentry_sdk.integrations.celery import CeleryIntegration

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="https://<YOUR_SENTRY_DSN>",
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration(), CeleryIntegration(monitor_beat_tasks=True)],
    traces_sample_rate=1.0,
    send_default_pii=True
)


for more info check Celery - Sentry, Django - Sentry docs
